# Problem in RibbonControlLibrary

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

I am facing an issue in Microsoft's `RibbonControlLibrary`. I have created a simple WPF application and I am using `RibbonControlLibrary` to create a ribbon bar on top. Problem is shown in image below.

[image]

Problem is that Menu under "Something" on only expand as much as there are items in left menu i.e. Item1, Item2... If I increase an item in left menu I get this[image]

but there are sill items missing in menu under Something.

below is XAML I am using

```
 <Ribbon:Ribbon ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CSIMRibbonTabs}">
            <Ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu CanUserResizeVertically="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainItem}">
                    <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                        <Grid> 
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border  >
                                <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Content="Something"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsControl  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OtherItems}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                </Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon:Ribbon>
```

code

```
 public List<string> MainItem
            {
            get
                {
                    return new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"};
                }
            }

        public List<string> OtherItems
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<string>() { "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6", "val7", "val8" };
            }
        }
```

What should I do to expand menu under "Something" as much as there are items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following attribute to your Grid element:
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

```
                <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent> 
                    <Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">  
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                            <RowDefinition /> 
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                        <Border  > 
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical"> 
                                <Label Content="Something"  /> 
                            </StackPanel> 
                        </Border> 
                        <ItemsControl  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OtherItems}"/> 
                    </Grid> 
                </Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
```